# Check current FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS value

Tags: mysql

How can I check what the current value of FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is?

I want to be sure that the value is 1.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check [5.1.5 Server System Variables::foreign_key_checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks):

```sql
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks, @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks;
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.foreign_key_checks | @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|                           1 |                            1 |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF((SELECT `VARIABLE_VALUE`
    -> FROM `performance_schema`.`global_variables`
    -> WHERE `VARIABLE_NAME` = 'foreign_key_checks') = 'ON', 1, 0) `global.foreign_key_checks`,
    -> IF((SELECT `VARIABLE_VALUE`
    -> FROM `performance_schema`.`session_variables`
    -> WHERE `VARIABLE_NAME` = 'foreign_key_checks') = 'ON', 1, 0) `session.foreign_key_checks`;
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| global.foreign_key_checks | session.foreign_key_checks |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|                         1 |                          1 |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why did you add the update? Just as an alternative way or are there versions after 5.1.5 that don't support the original solution? I'm wondering, because the original solution is far simpler and works for my MySQL 8 database.