# mysql error #1054 - Unknown column 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Here is my query:

```
IF FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 THEN
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
ELSE
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
END IF;
```

And my error is:

```
Error
Static analysis:
1 errors were found during analysis.
Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)
SQL query: Copy
IF FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 THEN SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS' in 'field list'
```

I don't know what is the problem and I want to toggle FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS variable it means if it's 0 change it to 1 and vice versa.

My database version is 10.4.11-MariaDB.

Anyone can help me??

Comment: If statements can only be used in stored programs (procedures,functions,triggers,events) is yours in a stored program?

Comment: No it doesn't but if it will work in that way can you make the codes just for this usage?

Comment: And check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763238/check-current-foreign-key-checks-value

Comment: Dear P.Salmon didn't work : "#1146 - Table 'performance_schema.global_variables' doesn't exist"